# Custom button to open window in visualforce, linking to the email object

Tags: salesforce, visualforce

```
         <tr data-field="@objecttype" data-caption="Type" />
              <tr data-field="@sfcontactname" data-caption="Candidate" />
              <tr data-field="@sfdepartment" data-caption="Department" />
              <tr><th>Email</th><td><%= email(raw.sfemail) %></td></tr>
              <tr data-field="@sfaccountname" data-caption="Candidate Company" />
              <tr data-field="@sfcontactfixedjobtitlec" data-caption="Fixed Job Title" />
              <tr data-field="@sfcontacttitle" data-caption="Legacy Job Title" />
              <tr data-field="@sfcontactfixedcategorytitlec" data-caption="Fixed Category Title" />
              <tr data-field="@sfcontactstatusc" data-caption="Status" />
              <tr data-field="@sfcontacthighestlevelofeducationc" data-caption="Highest Level of Education" />
              <tr data-field="@sfcontactlastnoteenteredactivityc" data-caption="Last Note Entered Activity" />
              <tr data-field="@sfcontactlastemailactivityc" data-caption="Last Email Activity" />
              <tr data-field="@sfleadsource" data-caption="Source of Candidate" />    
              <tr data-field="@sfcontactcommuteradiusc" data-caption="(IV) Commute Radius Miles" />
              <tr data-field="@sfcontactdesiredcompanysizec" data-caption="(IV) Desired Company Size" />
              <tr data-field="@sfcontactworkauthorizationc" data-caption="(IV)Work Authorization" />
              <tr data-field="@sfcontactassigntoexpertisec" data-caption="(IV) Assign to Expertise" />
              <tr data-field="@sfcontactpreferredenvironmentc" data-caption="(IV) Preferred Environment" />
              <tr data-field="@sfhomephone" data-caption="Home Phone" />
              <tr data-field="@sfmobilephone" data-caption="Mobile Phone" />
              <tr data-field="@sfcity" data-caption="City" />
              <tr data-field="@sfstate" data-caption="State" />
```

I want to add a button or URL to link to a specific URL in Salesforce (connecting to the email object), passing the Salesforce "@sfcontactname" into the url:

https://na15.salesforce.com/_ui/core/email/author/EmailAuthor?p2_lkid=003i000000JrLK3&rtype=003&retURL=%2F003i000000JrLK3AAN

Answer (score 0):

To pass data-field attribute value as a parameter from tr onclick event you can use this.attributes['data-field'].value

```
<tr data-field="@sfstate" data-caption="State" onclick="document.location.href = 'https://na15.salesforce.com/...' + this.attributes['data-field'].value"><td></td></tr>
```